# Objects (JSON or otherwise) as the value in a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I am trying to write a web application that has dependent menus and I think it would be best to just put in objects in the value fields so I can just the value of the checked fields.
The reason I am asking about putting in JSON instead of just the values is because I may need to put tuples of values in there later.

Ex:

```
var a = $('.optionsGroup:checked');
```

where a yields:

```
[ <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"optionsGroup" class=​"optionsGroup" id=​"optionsGroup" onclick=​"selectGroupFamily(this,1,'Math 8','class')​" value=​"{classId:​1}​">, 
  <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"optionsGroup" class=​"optionsGroup" id=​"optionsGroup" onclick=​"selectGroupFamily(this,3,'Math 9','class')​" value=​"{classId:​3}​"> ]
```

and the rest of the code:

```
var bar = function(key,val){
    console.log(val);
    console.log(typeof val);
    b = $(val);
    console.log(b.val()); 
    var obj = $.parseJSON(b.val()); //some error here saying unexpected type c
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.classId);
}
$.each(a,bar);
```

Ideally I'd like to get the output:

```
...html line...
string
object
1 etc.
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to work with?  Offhand I'd say check the content of value.  After $(val) - it needs to look something like: `value=​'{"classId":​3}​'` - Double quotes around the key

Comment: Yup, need a fiddle to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you change the JSON in value like

```
value='{"classId":"1"}'
```

Notice the double quotes around property name